# MySQL, PHP, How Many in GROUP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a table which outputs a list of users and how many times they've logged in.

A new row in the table is created every time that someone logs in so there is multiple rows for one user.

Now, I'm trying using the following statement to pull the data out:

```
SELECT * FROM logins GROUP BY user ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Which is working fine but now there is a column in my HTML table which should show how many times the user has logged in. How do I go about counting the amount of rows in each group?

Comment: Show us your php code and html, with this we see nothing

Comment: @Juan This is all we need, it's a simple query question.

Comment: @RickKuipers I misread, I guess..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS count FROM logins GROUP BY user ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Comment: I think COUNT(*) as count is better

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT user, count(timestamp) as login_count 
FROM logins
GROUP BY user
ORDER BY login_count DESC
```

to get the users ordered by the number of logins

Answer (score 1):

use count()...
try this

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) as totalcounts FROM logins GROUP BY user ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

The COUNT() function returns the number of rows that matches a specified criteria.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT user,count(*) as NoOfTimes
 FROM logins 
GROUP BY user 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `COUNT`:

```
SELECT user, COUNT(user) 'How Many Times he logged in'
FROM logins 
GROUP BY user 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```